# Get all texts inside h4, p etc tags and put it inside php gettext

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Hello all :) My client wants his wordpress site to be multilingual. The problem is that the php files with the content (in this case the tickets.php) have hardcoded html text. I must translate about 200 tags -- only in tickets.php, imagine in all the others files :'( --. I'll use poedit but first I need to wrap those tags with php gettext.

Lets say this is the code

```
<h1 class="text-center">Something something</h1>
```

And my target is to make it like this

```
<h1 class="text-center"><?php echo __('Something something','template_name');?></h1>
```

Its gonna take ages for all the text to be wrapped inside this. I'm using sublime text. I know that if select a text and press cntrl+shift+W, adds a tag in the selectes text. Is i possible to make a snippet to use it with `<?php echo __('SELECTED-TEXT','template_name');?>` ? Or something else?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only in 1 file ?
Try with NotePad++ to do a string/replace using a regexp.

I just tested that, it seems to works :

- Search str : `<h1 class="text-center">(.*)</h1>`
- Replace str : `<h1 class="text-center"><?php echo __\(addslashes\('$1'\),'template_name'\);?></h1>`

Do not forget to check "Regular expression" at bottom left.

edit :
Better version to handle all tags. I don't know if this is the best answer but it works

- Search str: `<(.*)>(.*)</(.*)>`
- Replace str: `<$1><?php echo __\(addslashes\('$2'\),'template_name'\);?></$3>`

Comment: As I said "I must translate about 200 tags -- only in tickets.php, imagine in all the others files :'( ", I mean that in tickets.php i have 200 translations, i have about 8 more php files. I dont have notepad++, i'm in OSX :)

Comment: Oops, sorry. Using "sed" (command line) will do the job. But I can't help you.

Comment: oh my god it worked with regular expressions. I forgot about them. Thank you so much. You saved me from very boring job :)

Answer (score 0):

Using sublime text you can edit all files contained in a folder using ctrl + shift + f and you can search using regular expression and replace with the appropriate content